# Is it possible to make an Equirectangular (spherical) camera projection in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Essentially I'm looking to make the field of view of the camera 360 degrees. I know it's not possible to make the field of view higher than 179 degrees, but how would I accomplish this effect using other methods?

I'm not looking to take a cube map or other equirectangular image and project it onto an inverted sphere, I'm looking to output my current scene in Unity to an  Equirectangular 'projection' in the game window, instead of the standard "Perspective" or "Orthographic" projection.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The link to the answer you provided, isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: I don't know that what you want is really possible with rasterization, I think you'd have to use raytracing, which is expensive and can't really be done in unity as far as I know. If it were possible, it would be done with a custom projection matrix, which I'm pretty sure unity lets you use, but from what I've seen [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128890/360-degree-video-of-my-opengl-game) it seems that a custom matrix would give strange distorted results.

Comment: Forget about the title of the duplicate. Read that answer. It has a `ConvertToEquirectangular` function that converts `Texture2D` to `Equirectangular` Texture2D. The result is stored in a  variable named `equiTexture`. Just capture image from your camera or get the render texture from it, convert it into Texture2D and send it to this function. Do whatever you want with that Equirectangular output image.